# ¿Como actualizar campos específicos de una cadena dentro de un documento txt?

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo de texto para almacenar los datos de jugadores con la siguiente estructura:

```
["robert", "GG™", "master", "1", "10"]
["carlos", "NC3", "user", "2", "22"]
["pepe", "NC2", "user", "3", "33"]
["juan", "TM2", "user", "4", "44"]
["carlos2", "TM1", "user", "5", "55"]
```

Este es el código que tengo para leer la lista de jugadores:

```
player=dict()
f = open("player.txt", "r")
for line in f.readlines():
  try:
    if len(line.strip())>0:
    user,team,rango,coins,exp= json.loads(line.strip())
    player[user] = json.dumps([team,rango,coins,exp])
  except:
   print("[Error] Cargando Jugadores: %s" % line)
f.close()
```

El código que muestro a continuación es para mostrar la linea donde el `user` es igual a `user.name` cuando se ejecuta el comando `"stats"`:

```
if cmd=="stats":
    user = user.name.lower()
    if user in player :
        team,rango,coins,exp = json.loads(player[user])
        string = " <b>Usuario:</b> "+user.capitalize()+" <br/> <b>Team:</b> "+team+" <br/> <b>Rango:</b> "+rango+" <br/> <b>Coins:</b> "+coins+" <br/> <b>Experiencia:</b>"+exp+" "
        room.message(string, True)
```

Mi pregunta es: **¿Cómo puedo actualizar ciertos campos de los usuarios en el txt?**

Es decir, si tengo la línea:

> ["user", "Team", "Rango", "Coins", "Exp"]

¿Cómo hago para actualizar el campo de `Coins` y `Exp` tomando el valor anterior y sumarlo con un numero aleatorio (`random.randint(1,20)`)?

Por ejemplo, si tengo la línea:

> ["robert", "GG™", "master", "1", "10"]

necesito modificar algunos datos para que quede algo así:

> ["robert", "GG™", "master", "7", "16"]

Todo ello sin afectar el valor de `user`, `team`, `rango` ni a los datos de los otros jugadores.

**Edición:**

He intentado lo siguente:

```
 if cmd=="coins":
     user = user.name.lower()
     if user in player:
         team,rango,coins,exp = json.loads(player[user])
         f = open("player.txt", "w")
         for user in player:
             team,rango,coins,exp = json.loads(player[user])
             rewardcoins = random.randint(1,20)
             rewardexp = random.randint(1,10)
             coins = int(coins) + rewardcoins
             exp = int(exp) + rewardexp
             coins = str(coins)
             exp = str(exp)
             f.write(json.dumps([user,team,rango,coins,exp])+"\n")
             room.message(""+user+""+team+""+rango+""+coins+""+exp+"", True)
         f.close()
```

El código no funciona del todo bien, me modifica los campos de `coins` y `exp` de todo los jugadores, si tengo:

> ["noiamg", "GG\u2122", "master", "1", "10"]
>   ["carlos", "NC3", "user", "2", "22"]
>   ["pepe", "NC2", "user", "3", "33"]
>   ["juan", "TM2", "user", "4", "44"]
>   ["carlos2", "TM1", "user", "5", "55"]

Obtengo:

> ["noiamg", "GG\u2122", "master", "9", "14"]
>   ["carlos", "NC3", "user", "10", "24"]
>   ["pepe", "NC2", "user", "21", "38"]
>   ["juan", "TM2", "user", "13", "45"]
>   ["carlos2", "TM1", "user", "20", "62"]

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Comment: Carga todos los datos en memoria, modificas los valores que quieras en memoria y luego reescribe el archivo con esos datos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder
tienes algún ejemplo no entiendo muy bien python

Comment: Rolando ya cargas tus datos en el diccionario player, solo tienes que modificar los datos en el diccionario y luego hacer el proceso inverso al que ya haces, pasar del diccionario al txt. ¿Has considerado usar un archivo de tipo json  para guardar los datos?, seria mucho mas simple cargar y guardar los datos.

Comment: @FJSevilla he el código (esta arriba)
pero no me esta funcionando muy bien 
me cambia todo los valores de coins y exp de todo los jugadores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas reescribiendo lo datos de todos los jugadores. Debes modificar los datos del usuario en el diccionario y posteriormente recorres todo el diccionario reescribiendo el archivo. Deberías hacer algo así

```
import json
import random

player = {}
with open("player.txt", "r") as f:    
    for line in (l.strip() for l in f.readlines()):
        if line:
            try:
                user, team, rango, coins, exp= json.loads(line)
                player[user] = [team,rango,coins,exp]
            except:
                print("[Error] Cargando Jugadores: %s" % line)


if cmd == "coins":
    user = user.name.lower()

    if user in player:
        team, rango, coins, exp = player[user]           
        rewardcoins = random.randint(1,20)
        rewardexp = random.randint(1,10)
        coins = str(int(coins) + rewardcoins)
        exp = str(int(exp) + rewardexp)
        player[user] = [team, rango, coins, exp]

        with open("player.txt", "w")  as f:
            for user in player:
                f.write(json.dumps([user, *player[user]], ensure_ascii=False)+"\n")

        out = ("<b>{}</b><f x11ac4c39='0'> ganaste <f x12ff7733='0'>"
               "<b>{}</b> <f x11ff7733='0'>gemas<f x11ac4c39='0'> y "
               "<f x1276a800='0'><b>{}</b> <f x1176a800='0'>de experiencia.")
        room.message(out.format(str(user).capitalize(), rewardcoins,  rewardexp), True)
```

Podrias hacer lo mismo usando cadenas formateadas en vez de usar `json.dump`, no obstante, ya que lo usas lo he mantenido. Lo que si hago es usar el parámetro  `ensure_ascii=False` para que no escape los caracteres no ascii al escribir en el txt. Dado el txt que muestras se intuye que usa UTF-8 como codificación.

Por otro lado, sería mucho más simple guardar los datos como un archivo json válido. Esto te permite guardar y recuperar los datos como un diccionario Python válido directamente. Si vas a almacenar muchos datos mejor usar algo más eficiente como una base de datos, lo más simple es usar sqlite que ya viene por defecto con Python.

Comment: Funciona perfecto el único inconveniente es que me imprime todo los nombres en la consola y room.message

Comment: @RolandoHuaihuaMerma lo de imprimir en consola los nombres es porque me deje un `print` de prueba, eso esta corregido. En cuanto a lo de `room`, no se que pretendes hacer ni que debe recibir ese método, ya que no lo muestras. Si me dices cuales deben ser sus parámetros y u estructura exacta te puedo ayudar, la he comentado mientras tanto.

Comment: room.message es como un print solo que el room.message no se imprime en la consola, se imprime en un chat de usuarios

Comment: Vale @RolandoHuaihuaMerma pero ¿debe imprimir los datos de todos los usuarios o solo el que modifica?. Por otro lado, supongo que debe recibir una cadena como primer argumento, si es así ¿cual es su formato?, es decir ¿cual es la cadena que debe recibir, por ejemplo para `["robert", "GG™", "master", "1", "10"]`?

Comment: he logrado arreglarlo 
no se si sea la manera correcta 
aquí esta la variable nueva: iduser = str(user)

room.message(""+iduser+""+team+""+rango+""+coins+""+exp+"", True)

Comment: solo el dato que se modifica

Comment: solo era un ejemplo 
el código ya lo he modificado y lo tengo así:
room.message("<b>"+iduser.capitalize()+"</b><f x11ac4c39='0'> ganaste <f x12ff7733='0'><b>"+str(rewardcoins)+"</b> <f x11ff7733='0'>gemas<f x11ac4c39='0'> y <f x1276a800='0'><b>"+str(rewardexp)+"</b> <f x1176a800='0'>de experiencia.", True)

Comment: Vale, ok. Solo es que me parecía raro lo de los string vacios. Podrías usar `str.format`. Te evitas los casting implícitos y queda más legible el código. Voy a modificar la respuesta para mostrarlo en un momento. Recuerda que puedes aceptar aquella respuesta que te sea de ayuda para resolver tu problema, mírate: [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427/15089) para más información Un saludo.

Comment: ok muchas  gracias por la ayuda.